# spring test @Value not being populated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm trying to run unit tests in spring-test and I cannot get the @Value to populate in the Injected Classes.. My looks like this.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    RelationshipCacheFactoryImpl.class,
    IgniteBoot.class,
    ServerMarker.class})
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class RelationshipCacheFactoryImplTest {
...
```

So in my IgniteBoot class I have this

```
@Component
public class IgniteBoot {
   Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IgniteBoot.class);

   @Autowired
   ApplicationContext context;

   @Autowired
   IgniteClientConfig clientConfig;

   @Value("${ignite.tcp.finder:MULTICAST}")
   String tcpFinder;

   @Value("${ignite.tcp.finder.sharedfs.path:/tmp}")
   String fsFinderPath;

   @Value("${ignite.name:tempGrid}")
   String name;

   @Value("${ignite.roles:testRole}")
   String roles;

   @Value("${ignite.h2Debug:false}")
   String h2DebugStr;

   ...
```

The @Value annotated Strings are all populated with the values in the $Value String, but not with the actual values from the properties file.

Any Idea what this could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to your test configuration:

```
        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }
```

In your test you don't use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` (separetly or implicitly as part of `@SpringBootApplication`) which registers this bean for you in the application, so you need to register it yourself.